# Do we really need to cool down Stack Overflow using the 'fan' tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Imagine someone just posted a question tagged with "fan". Let's go and answer it. Will it be about a Facebook fan, a PC fan, or a wall-mounted fan?

Do you agree that the [fan](/questions/tagged/fan) tag is totally meaningless? It has 81 posts tagged under it.

<sub>I hope [Trogdor](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/Trogdor) is not on vacation or helping out Santa to ...</sub>

Comment: At least one's about a GL_TRIANGLE_FAN also. *Most* are about Facebook, though.

Comment: yeah the tag-wiki says it as PC fan, but misused for Social networking .

Comment: [If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I think [fan] fits this criteria perfectly.

Comment: I'd say this is a good candidate for burnination. It's not particularly useful in *any* of the situations it's being used.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stack Overflow tags and the request is already [status-completed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a no-life I've retagged all questions with [fan](/questions/tagged/fan) tag related to facebook to the [facebook-fanpage](/questions/tagged/facebook-fanpage) tag. Most of other questions using the [fan](/questions/tagged/fan) tag seem to fit the current definition:

> A computer fan is any fan inside, or attached to, a computer case used for active cooling, and may refer to fans that draw cooler air into the case from the outside, expel warm air from inside, or move air across a heatsink to cool a particular component.

However these two questions:

- [First impressions of the Fantom programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133528/first-impressions-of-the-fan-programming-language)
- [How can I hide the command prompt in my FWT application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566291/fan-programming-language)

suggest that the [fan](/questions/tagged/fan) tag should mean something else. Also, most of these questions I've processed should be closed - but I've ran out of close votes.

Comment: The "Fan" programming language is [now known as Fantom](http://fantom.org/), which has its own tag now ([tag:fantom]). I've proposed edits and retags on both those Fantom questions.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you go through and disambiguate some of them before requesting the final burnination - so that people can tell the difference between [cpu-fan](/questions/tagged/cpu-fan) and [facebook-fan](/questions/tagged/facebook-fan). Note that there is already a [facebook-fanpage](/questions/tagged/facebook-fanpage) which might be a candidate for some of the retags.

Once the facebook ones and the few remaining legitimate ones are done, all that's left can be fried in last year's turkey fat.

Comment: Question is if [facebook-fan] would be a valid tag.

Comment: There are now [no questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fan+facebook) tagged with both [[tag:facebook]] and [[tag:fan]] - they've been retagged to [[tag:facebook-fanpage]].

Answer (score 1):

Given the description of the tag, it seems that the `fan` tag should be removed from the questions using "Facebook fan" (and similar) interpretations.

**Description of the tag:**

> A computer fan is any fan inside, or attached to, a computer case used for active cooling, and may refer to fans that draw cooler air into the case from the outside, expel warm air from inside, or move air across a heatsink to cool a particular component.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fan

The longer info supports this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fan/info

Comment: Having a tag description does not mean that the tag existence is valid. I am questioning about if the tag is valid for Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: Fair -- my point was simply that the fan tag *shouldn't* be meaningless, its definition should prevent wondering whether it's about "Facebook fan, PC fan," etc. @slugster spelled out my point a bit more explicitly by suggesting disambiguation -- once the tag is only applied to questions which actually match the tag's topic, it'll at least be clearer what we're dealing with.

Comment: Valid argument but I think "fan" is invalid because of this: [If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212815/do-we-really-need-to-cool-down-stack-overflow-using-the-fan-tag/212825?noredirect=1#comment685086_212815)

Comment: @AzizShaikh: I look forward to your request to burninate [windows].

Comment: @Wooble to programmers _windows_ mainly relates to a OS built by MS but _fan_ is open to interpretations

Comment: @AzizShaikh: as a programmer, to me "windows" are a UI element. I'd have to read the tag wiki summary to know that the tag shouldn't be used to talk about them.